# 404 oAuth token API

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

Ghost error, please read before mark as duplicate.
I am facing very strange problem,

I have internet connectivity receiver

```
private void connectionChange(Context foContext, Intent foIntent) {
    boolean lbIsNetworkAvaibale = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) foContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (currentNetworkInfo != null)
        if (currentNetworkInfo.isAvailable())
            lbIsNetworkAvaibale = currentNetworkInfo.isConnected();

    Log.i(TAG, "Network Available is: " + lbIsNetworkAvaibale);
    if (!lbIsNetworkAvaibale) {
        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) foIntent
                .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (otherNetworkInfo != null)
            if (otherNetworkInfo.isAvailable())
                lbIsNetworkAvaibale = otherNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Network Available New is: " + lbIsNetworkAvaibale);
    if (lbIsNetworkAvaibale) {
        // Calling the method and from that method call token api using volley will give you code below.
    } else {
        // stop all service and alarms  
   }
}
```

Volley code

```
public static int callVolleyPostRequest(final boolean fbIsRefreshToken, final Context foContext, final RefreshTokenResponses loRefreshTokenResponses) {

    String lsRequestURL = "http://my.domain/auth/token";

    final SharedPreferenceManager loSharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManager(foContext);
    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, lsRequestURL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Volley Response : " + response);

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response)) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject loJsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            if ((loJsonResponse.length() <= 0)) {
                                loRefreshTokenResponses.onResponse(400);
                                return;
                            } else {
                                //storing token in preference
                                loRefreshTokenResponses.onResponse(200);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.logException(TAG, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if (error == null || error.networkResponse == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Volley Error null");
                return;
            }

            String body = "";
            //get status code here
            int liStatusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
            loRefreshTokenResponses.onResponse(liStatusCode);

            //get response body and parse with appropriate encoding
            try {
                body = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // exception
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.i(TAG, "Error body : " + body);

            Log.i(TAG, "Volley Error code : " + liStatusCode);

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getUrl() {
            String lsUrl = super.getUrl();
            Log.i(TAG, "Volley token request URL : " + lsUrl);
            return lsUrl;
        }



        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "fbIsRefreshToken  : " + fbIsRefreshToken);
                HashMap<String, String> loStringRequest = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try {

                    if (!fbIsRefreshToken) {

                      loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.USERNAME.toString(), TextUtils.isEmpty(loSharedPreferenceManager.getUserName()) ? "" : loSharedPreferenceManager.getUserName());
                            loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.PASSWORD.toString(), TextUtils.isEmpty(loSharedPreferenceManager.getPassword()) ? "" : loSharedPreferenceManager.getPassword());
                            loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.GRANT_TYPE.toString(), Constants.TOKEN.PASSWORD.toString());
                            int liLoginType = loSharedPreferenceManager.getLoginType() == 0 ? 1 : loSharedPreferenceManager.getLoginType();
                            loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.LOGINTYPE.toString(), "" + liLoginType);

                    } else {
                        loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.REFRESH_TOKEN.toString(), TextUtils.isEmpty(loSharedPreferenceManager.getRefreshToken()) ? "" : loSharedPreferenceManager.getRefreshToken());
                        loStringRequest.put(Constants.TOKEN.GRANT_TYPE.toString(), Constants.TOKEN.REFRESH_TOKEN.toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.logException(TAG, e);

                    Log.i(TAG, "Exception  getToken ");
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Volley token build param : " + getPostData(loStringRequest));
                return getPostData(loStringRequest).getBytes();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppGlobal.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "Token");
    return 0;
}
```

Error log

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
         <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
           <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
         <style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
 </style>
   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
   <p>The requested URL <code>/auth/token</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

HTML says

[image]

Now the strange is while i test the app all working fine(even i test in 2g net with 100 time connect and disconnect internet) after 5 to 10 hours somehow internet connectivity change 2 3 time and from that attempt the token request starting 404 error for both call(Get access token using refresh token and get new token using unm pass). and this will continue, and while i force stop the app from settings and again open the app it will start working fine :(.

I suspect that the issue is from backend side, but as i say while i force restart app it will working. and backend code working well.

FYI:- I had used Asynctask first but face the error so replace with volley, Authentication mechanism is oAuth 2.0, not Google, and the app continues working in background.

Please avoid grammar :) and help. stuck from many days.